# Add event listener on scroll of dropdown select options and fetch data using react-async-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

how to implement paginated option loading in react-async-select on scroll of options

```
      <AsyncSelect ref={scrollRef} defaultOptions cacheOptions loadOptions={this.loadOptions} />
```

[code sand box link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-async-1ti5m?from-embed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

using this prop `onMenuScrollToBottom={(e) => handleOnScrollBottom(e)}` :
*Fired when the user scrolls to the bottom of the menu* from [react-select doc](https://react-select.com/props#select-props)

```
<AsyncSelect onMenuScrollToBottom={(e) => handleOnScrollBottom(e)} defaultOptions cacheOptions loadOptions={this.loadOptions} />
```